# Using Powershell, how to add a task sequence for installing an SCCM package

Tags: powershell, sccm

My Google-FU is not working today.  I am needing to automate adding steps to a series of Task Sequences that simply install a SCCM package.  I have automated the package creation, Task Sequence creation.  Now just need to add the one step to the Task Sequence.  Basically Add Step/Software/Install Package...  Name it, and point to the already created package (preferably via Name, but can use Package ID if needed).

Any Ideas?  Microsoft's documentation is woeful at best.  Found several examples of adding Command Line steps, but nothing for Packages.

TIA
Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly we need to create "install software" step using `New-CMTSStepInstallSoftware`, then add the step into TS using `Add-CMTaskSequenceStep`.

This is an example.

```
$a = Get-CMProgram -PackageName "YOURPACKAGENAME"
$b = New-CMTSStepInstallSoftware -Program $a -Name test
Get-CMTaskSequence -Name "YOURTSNAME" | Add-CMTaskSequenceStep -Step $b -InsertStepStartIndex 1
```

Best Regards,
Ray

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  I added my csv portion and it worked great!